# Timing rapid events

Tags: timer, measurement, benchmarking

I'd like to measure the amount of time taken to complete a rapid event but the time taken is comparable to the accuracy of my timer. Can I measure the distribution of times taken to perform the operation several times and then reverse engineer the underlying distribution, i.e. solve p₁= p₂* p₂ using deconvolution?

Comment: Have you tried to use clock cycles as time measurement unit? Try: https://github.com/petersenna/rdtscbench